# want to show image OnItemClick on listview item in dialog box

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

I want to show a image on click item of listview which is showing in dialog.
But as I click on item is Image is showing in multiple items
Can anyone suggest me how to do this.

```
  listQuantity.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               view.findViewById(R.id.img_check).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you also need to reset previous clicked item image to `INVISIBLE` before setting current clicked item image VISIBLE.

Comment: I did reset previous clicked item but when I clicked again any other item there are showing  multiple image on different items.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use to optimize your listview holder, you could upload the code you're using to help better

http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-listview-optimizations

http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296